# Proof that continuous function respects sequential continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, proof-verification

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $f:A\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a continuous function. I want to prove that if a sequence $(x_k)\subset A$ converges to some $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ then $f(x_k)$ converges to $f(a)$. Here's my attempt:

Since $f$ is continuous, $\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists \delta >0 $  such that $\|f(x)-f(a)\|<\varepsilon$ whenever $\|x-a\|<\delta$. Also, since $(x_k)$ converges to $a$, $\forall\varepsilon' > 0$, $\exists k_0 \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\|x_k-a\|<\varepsilon'$ whenever $k\ge k_0$. Let $\varepsilon'>0$ and set $\varepsilon'' = \varepsilon+\varepsilon'$, and fix $k\ge k_0$. Since $f$ is continuous, then $\exists \delta' >0$ such that $\|f(x)-f(x_k)\|<\varepsilon'$ whenever $\|x-x_k\|<\delta'$. Now, $\|f(x_k)-f(a)\|=\|f(x_k)-f(x)+f(x)-f(a)\|\le$
$\|f(x)-f(x_k)\|+\|f(x)-f(a)\|<\varepsilon'+\varepsilon= \varepsilon''$. Hence, $f$ respects sequential continuity.

Do you think my proof is OK? Thanks.

Comment: Take delta instead of epsilon prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof does not look sound. Saying $\|f(x)-f(x_k)\|<\varepsilon'$ whenever $\|x-x_k\|<\delta'$ makes sense if $x_k\to x$. The tails of the sequence cannot be close to $x$ and $a$ at the same time unless $x=a$ (otherwise $\varepsilon''$ cannot be made arbitrary small).

The idea is more straightforward here: by definition

1. Since $f$ continuous we have
   $$
   \forall \varepsilon>0\,\exists \color{red}\delta >0\text{ such that } \|f(\color{blue}x)-f(a)\|<\varepsilon,\text{ for all }\color{blue}x\colon \|\color{blue}x-a\|<\color{red}\delta.
   $$
2. Since $x_k\to a$ we have
   $$
   \forall\color{red}\delta>0\,\exists k_0 \in\mathbb{N}\text{ such that } \|\color{blue}{x_k}-a\|<\color{red}\delta,\text{ for all } k\ge k_0.
   $$

We see that for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $\color{red}\delta>0$ in 1, then for this $\color{red}\delta$ find $k_0\in\Bbb N$ in 2. The tails of $\color{blue}{x_k}$ satisfy then $\|\color{blue}{x_k}-a\|<\color{red}\delta$, so we can take $\color{blue}x=\color{blue}x_k$ in 1 to conclude that for the tails $\|f(\color{blue}{x_k})-f(a)\|<\varepsilon$. We started from any $\varepsilon$ and ended up with the proper $k_0$, thus, obtained the sequential continuity by definition.

Comment: @A.Γ. What concerns me is that, since $f$ is not necessarily uniformly continuous, how can we ensure that $\|f(x_k)-f(a)\|<\varepsilon$ holds if $x\ne x_k$? I guess I need to stress that the idea is that $x_k$ approaches $a$. Otherwise, this technique wouldn't work.

Comment: @sequence You are not changing $a$, so no uniform continuity is necessary here. The variable $x$ is dummy variable, it just means "any point". If any point is close enough to $a$ then the functional value at that point is close to $f(a)$. Then we can take $x_k$ as "any point", since $x_k$ is close enough to $a$, that is, it satisfies the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon>0$.

$f $ continuous at $a  \implies$

$\exists \delta_{a,\epsilon}>0$ such that $\|f (x)-f (a)\| $ whenever $\|x-a\|<\delta_{a,\epsilon}$

but $\lim x_n =a $ thus

$\exists N_0$ such that

$\|x_n-a\|<\delta_{a,\epsilon} $ whenever $n>N_0$.

finally
$n>N_0\implies \|x_n-a\|<\delta_{a,\epsilon}\implies \|f (x_n)-f (a)\|<\epsilon $

$\implies \lim_{+\infty}f(x_n)=f (a) $.

Comment: I've done this approach as well, but $f$ is not *uniformly* continuous, so we don't have that $\exists \delta$ which satisfies all $x$ ($x_k\ne x$). That is $\|x-a\|<\delta\implies \|f(x)-f(a)\|<\epsilon$ does not mean that $\|x_k-a\|<\delta \implies \|f(x_k)-f(a)\|<\epsilon$. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I did not use uniform continuity. I edited some lines.

Comment: For the limit of $x_n $, since it is true for all $\epsilon'$, it is also true in particular for $\delta $.